# XPathDocument behavior with DOCTYPE declaration

Tags: .net, xml-parsing, doctype, xpathdocument

I use [XPathDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathdocument.aspx) to parse an XML file, but if there's a [doctype declaration](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp), when I initializes a new instance of the XPathDocument class passing the path of the file, that contains the XML data, to its constructor, my application tries to connect to internet (probably to verify the correctness of the XML data) and remains blocked for a long period of time. This does not occur if I delete the doctype declaration from the XML file. [XmlDocument.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx) method has the same behavior.
How can I fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: It the file is actually an HTML file, a lot of people find HTML Agility Pack good for parsing the elements:  http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: It's a [SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/) file.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the XPathDocument constructor that takes an XmlReader as its input, you can set an [XmlResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlurlresolver.aspx) on the XmlReader. Then you can set the resolver to recognise the SVG doctype and supply a local copy of the SVG DTD.

Similarly, XmlDocument can also be given an XmlResolver before calling the Load method.

Comment: You could give me an example with XPathDocument?